# Authentication failed. Please make sure that you added your private key to the ssh preferences

Tags: eclipse, ssh, glassfish, jersey, openshift

I am trying to deploy Jersey project with openshift eclipse plugin but I am getting this error `Authentication failed. Please make sure that you added your private key to the ssh preferences` I have gernerated to ssh key and saved it in the .ssh directory. I added this key on the openshif- seetings- add new key- I named it id_rsa like my stored one in the .git directory.

[image]

openshift ssh key:

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve this?

Comment: @user3629892 are u still facing this Problem?  I solved it after clicking in the finish Dialog --> SSH Key wizard --> and  clicking `Default` in the Manage SHH key Dialog.

Comment: well, I only have the default ssh key and it still gives me the same error. I have no idea what the hell is going on...

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse tooling needs the private key that matches your public key in OpenShit. Otherwise git in Eclipse cannot clone the git repo in OpenShift. Make sure that you have the private key set in the Eclipse SSH2 preferences.

Another possible reason is (i dont habe enough details to know) if you're telling the OpenShift host to install a cartridge that is available in source from a git repo that OpenShift should clone. The above error shows you using an ssh-git-url. In this case you would have to make sure that the OpenShift host has the private key to clone from the git repo with the source code. This known issue is easily to work around using cartreflect as descrbed here:

- https://issues.jboss.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JBIDE-18866
- https://issues.jboss.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JBIDE-18911

For details on how to install the PRIVATE ssh key in OpenShift so that it can clone using an ssh-git-url look here:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1163964#c0

Cheers
André

Comment: The last link doesn't work anymore. Do you know where the documentation on this is now?